# Requesting an extension for revision due to being on holiday

Tags: publications, peer-review, deadlines

I submitted an article on the first of May, and just got the comments from the reviewers today (31st of October).

The editor specified that I have 2 weeks to address the comments, but I am going on a hiking holiday in 4 days for 3 weeks, and this was planned already at the start of the year.

Is being on holiday a valid reason to ask for an extension? This is my first article ever, so I am not quite sure of the rules.

The journal page says that you can ask for an extension for valid reasons, so I'm wondering whether a holiday is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Just ask for it and don't worry**

These "deadlines" for revisions aren't real deadlines. Journals simply [quote something](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/194031/why-do-journals-set-deadlines) to keep the authors thinking about the manuscript and the journal orderly (since some authors will withdraw the manuscript by never submitting a revision).

If you need more time, just tell them and they'll adjust the schedule accordingly; in particular, their automated reminders will not be sent until you're back from holiday.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I was almost panicking thinking of how my holiday would be ruined, and was considering just withdrawing the manuscript and sending it to a different journal (which my supervisor wouldn't be so happy about). 

I'll send the editor an email asking for an extension.

Comment: Also: simply don't describe your reasons other than: "We are confident that we can address all reviewer comments in full. However, due to prior commitments, we will be unable to complete these revisions within the allotted time frame. Would it be possible to extend the deadline to <new deadline>?"